# Counting the number of rows between transitions of values in SQL

Tags: sql, presto, gaps-and-islands

I have rows with user_id, timestamps and YES / NO answer. I want to count how many streaks (consecutive rows) of "NO"s each ID has.

Example:

| user_id | timestamp | response | no_streak |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 13:59:26 | YES | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:01:27 | NO | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:03:21 | NO | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:07:29 | NO | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:09:22 | YES | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:11:26 | YES | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:13:30 | NO | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:17:26 | NO | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:19:29 | YES | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:25:30 | NO | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:27:23 | NO | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:31:23 | NO | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:35:27 | NO | 4 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 14:39:24 | YES | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-01-20 14:39:24 | NO | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-01-20 14:47:28 | NO | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-01-20 14:49:22 | NO | 3 |
| 2 | 2021-01-20 14:51:25 | NO | 4 |
| 2 | 2021-01-20 14:53:29 | NO | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-01-20 14:55:22 | NO | 6 |
| 2 | 2021-01-20 14:57:22 | YES | 0 |

Ultimately I'd like to know for each user how long the streaks were:

| user_id | streak length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 6 |

I'm able to use `LAG()` to find where "NO"s transition to "YES" and vice-versa, but I'm struggling to then count the # of rows that sit between each transition.

Comment: explain whats the logic behind showing streak length = 0 for each user_id

Comment: @eshirvana that's not a requirement, but I wanted to at least show what could be the case. If a user had all `YES` responses, then they could either be left out entirely, or be recorded as a streak length of `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the number of "yes"s up to each row so the adjacent NOs have the same grouping value.  Then filter and aggregate:

```
select t.user_id, count(*), min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when response = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where response = 'NO'
group by user_id, grp;
```

Note:  This doesn't return streaks of `0` length.  I'm not sure of "streak" is the right word for that.  But to get them, remove the `where` filter and use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.user_id, sum(case when response = 'NO' then 1 else 0 end),
       min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when response = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id, grp;
```